# Thread 1: SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

This is my first question (and program in Xcode to be honest) so apologies if I break any formatting rules, etc!

I am having an issue when creating an area calculator (to be used at a later date in a quote calculator) and having looked at every SIGABRT thread I could find, but I have been unable to resolve it.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController{
@IBOutlet weak var forename: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var surname: UITextField!    
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!    
@IBOutlet weak var widthInput: UITextField! 
@IBOutlet weak var lengthInput: UITextField!    
@IBOutlet weak var areaOutput: UILabel!    
@IBOutlet weak var perimeterOutput: UILabel!    
@IBOutlet weak var results: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

    let width = NSString(string: widthInput.text).doubleValue
    let length = NSString(string: lengthInput.text).doubleValue

    // The calculation used to work out the area of a room
    var area = width * length
    areaOutput.text =  "\(area)"

    // The calculation used to work out the perimeter of a room
    var perimeter = 2 * (length + width)
    perimeterOutput.text =  "\(perimeter)"


}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Marc

Comment: Please post at which line do you get an exception.

Comment: On the breakpoint navigator, you could add an exception breakpoint. This will tell you the exactly lines were is crashing.

Comment: My quick quess is that your code braks at the first line of code below IBAction func calculate... The reason for this might be that your widthInput or any other TextField object is nil and you are not checking anywhere for nil. It doesn't have to be widthInput, it can be lenghtInput or any other element. Since you textfields may be empty (not edited) the .text property is nil and then you try to access it as if nil were a NSString which it isn't. The fastest way to check is to comment all code i IBAction and then test it. If it works then the bug is somewhere in this function.

Comment: Sorry, had a busy couple of weeks and haven't had a chance to come back to this!

http://i.imgur.com/Sn7yTsc.png

I don't know if that would help explain what's going on?
Marc